# Installation of Skype for Ubuntu 14.04 x64 with Terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line, skype

I'm new to Ubuntu and try to install the latest version of Skype from terminal  windows. Can anybody help me please, How to do this?

Answer (score 21):

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype...

> **Installing Skype**
>
> Users of 64-bit Ubuntu, should enable MultiArch if it
>   isn't already enabled by running the command
>
> `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
>
> Since Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx),
>   Skype is part of the Canonical partner repository. To install Skype
>   add the Canonical Partner Repository. You can do this by running the
>   command
>
> `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"`
>
> Then install Skype via the Software-Center
>   or via the Terminal.
>
> `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype pulseaudio:i386`

Comment: I didn't need to install pulseaudio:i386. It seems to be working without it.

Comment: @DavidHalter good to hear!  Glad you got it working, either way.

Comment: For me installing pulseaudio:i386 actually killed the audio system altogether (Ubuntu MATE 14.04.5), so be careful with it.

Comment: @egor83 the same happened with me (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS).

Answer (score 7):

You simply need to add the partner repository :

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Comment: This is a bad advice. If this command is run twice, or partner repository is already on, this command will lead to inability to install anything.

Comment: I am not sure it works this way, but at least no harm. But it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded skype for linux from its website. 
https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/

Then ran command `sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb`