# Skype and MS Office on a Ubuntu laptop

Tags: skype

I recently purchased a Dell Latitude 3550 with Ubuntu as default OS. I had always planned to install Windows 10. However I found that the Ubuntu OS was supportive of net access using WIFI, had its own version of MS office tools though not as refined as MS Office.I am now getting second thoughts on installing Win 10.

I am a heavy Skype user. Is Skype compatible with Ubuntu?

Can I install MS Office on Ubuntu without resorting to Win 10?

Would appreciate your advice.

Comment: "its own version of MS office tools" There is no "MS Office" for Ubuntu, since Microsoft does not want you to install it on Linux. It might work through Wine, but it is always a bet. There are alternatives, like LibreOffice, that are available on Linux, Mac, Windows, Android and many other platforms, while MS Office does not support even a basic Linux. Skype is compatible, since in this case Microsoft has provided us with a binary, but again, they made it crippled for Linux. Please consider also in this case to switch to one of the many better alternatives.

Comment: see this answer for skype installation: http://askubuntu.com/questions/654658/installation-of-skype-for-ubuntu-14-04-x64-with-terminal

Comment: There is no MS Office for Linux; I use LibreOffice and it has all the features I need.

Comment: For MS Office, you can install Kingsoft/WPS office. I find it better than LibreOffice - http://askubuntu.com/questions/235951/can-kingsoft-office-be-installed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software or games?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Skype?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)

Answer (score 1):

for sure, there is a [skype-client](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/) for linux-based systems!

it is even available in the repositories, so it integrates in your package system and will be updated like all the other software in one place! - please have a look at this question: [How do I install Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)

---

MS Office is not available for Linux-based systems but you can try to install the windows-version via [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29).

it might get a bit tricky, so please read this questions first:
[Can I install Microsoft Office? If so, how?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156296/can-i-install-microsoft-office-if-so-how)
[Installing MS Office 2013 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350167/installing-ms-office-2013-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts)

although i suggest you to try [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) (it is installed by default and nearly equal featured as MS Office) and maybe also the free standardized odf-format!
IMHO most people don't need MS Office anyway... they just want a familiar GUI: so if you like the WinXP/2003-look you will love LibreOffice, if you want the Win7/2007-look maybe give [WPS Office](http://www.wps.com/) a try for a native office suite: [Can Kingsoft Office be installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235951/can-kingsoft-office-be-installed)

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is a version for skype in ubuntu. [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/skype-4-3-install-in-ubuntu-1404/) This will help you to install skype. 
And for MS office representative, there is Libreoffice which is pre-installed in ubuntu. It's quite decent. If you really want to use MS office you can use it's online version [MS office](https://www.office.com/)